# How to retrieve an input form value with redux-form and formValueSelector

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to retrieve a single input value and log it.  This is an edit form with existing name value prop.

I am not setting state 'name' with field input's value for some reason.  I am not sure how to structure the connect part which I think is my problem. In particular, I am not clear on how to write mapStateToProps to include both my non-form state and form state.

partial scaled down code:

```
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateStable } from '../../actions/index';

const selector = formValueSelector('myEditForm');

class EditStuff extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initialize({
      name: this.props.name || ''
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // this.state.name is not getting set from input value
    this.props.updateLocalActiveStuffData(this.state.name);

  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>

          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
            <Field
              label="Name"
              name="name"
              class="name"
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
            />

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    displayEditForm: state.displayEditForm,  //my own non-form related state
    name: selector(state, 'name') //form input 'name'
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateStuff })(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'myEditForm'
  })(EditStuff)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can't retrieve the value it's because the name of your form in reduxForm and the formValueSelector name are different  `'StableEditForm' != 'myEditForm'`
[You have more info on selectors here](https://redux-form.com/6.1.0/examples/selectingformvalues/)

---

If you want to initialise your form with values, you should set it from your state in `mapStateToProps` with the `initialValues` props, something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    initialValues: state.displayEditForm, // value of your form
 };
}
```

[A great exemple here](https://redux-form.com/6.1.0/examples/initializefromstate/)

I hope this can help you

Comment: The form name difference was a copy/paste typo -I edited  question.  I'll check out your recommended way of setting initialValues.